# Diseño layout con bottomNavigation

Tags: android, android-layout

tengo un problema con el diseño de un layout, tiene un toolBar, un fragmentLayout y un bottomtNavegation, pero el problema es que el contenido del fragment se coloca detras y no se ajusta debajo del toolbar y sobre el bottomNavegation.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el xml de layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.cspm.ventas4.cspm.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.cspm.ventas4.cspm.MainActivity"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_clientes"
        android:id="@+id/main_container">

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="55dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Que esta mal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al crear un layout que incorpora la `BottomNavigation` con el asistente de android-studio 2.3

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.webserveis.app.imagestudio.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:text="@string/dummy_text_large" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</LinearLayout>
```